# d3.stack() TypeError: Cannot read property ' ' of undefined

Tags: javascript, d3.js, stacked-area-chart

Trying to build a Streamgraph in v5 but this is so different to v3.

It makes sense to have:

```
.x(function(d) { return formatDate.parse(d.Year);})
.y(function(d) { return +d["HIV/AIDS"] });
```

but I guess this is a d3 v3 code that became obsolete. Instead am using keys.

console.log("New nested data:", newData); gives layers: undefined

What am I doing wrong?

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/ekilja01/pen/BvLqyR)

Data:

```
key: "Zambia"
values: Array(14)
0: {Country: "Zambia", Year: "Year 2000",  HIV/AIDS: 3042, …}
1: {Country: "Zambia", Year: "Year 2001",  HIV/AIDS: 3170, …}
2: {Country: "Zambia", Year: "Year 2002",  HIV/AIDS: 3159, …}
```

Code:

```
//Stack generator
var stack = d3.stack()
.keys(function(d){return +d["HIV/AIDS"]})
.order(d3.stackOrderNone)
.offset(d3.stackOffsetNone)

//Line generator 
let area= d3.area()
    .x(function(d) {
        return xScale(dateFormat(d.Year));
    })
    .y0(function(d){
        return yScale(d.y0);

    })
    .y1(function(d){
        return yScale(d.y0 + d.y)
    })
//group data by country name
    let newData = d3.nest()
        .key(function(d) {
            return d.Country;
        })
        .sortKeys(d3.descending)
        .sortValues(function(a, b) {
            return dateFormat(a.Year) - dateFormat(b.Year);
        })
        .entries(data);

var layers = stack(newData);
    console.log("layers", layers); 
//Define yScale domain after data loaded
yScale.domain([d3.max(data, function(d) {
    return +d["HIV/AIDS"]
}), 0]);


svg.selectAll("path")
    .data(layers)
    .enter()
    .append("path")
    .classed("line", true)
    .attr("d", function(d){
        return area(+d["HIV/AIDS"])
    })
    .style("fill", "url(#linear-gradient)")
```

Comment: Have you gone through the [documentation](https://github.com/d3/d3-shape/blob/master/README.md#_stack) for `d3.stack()`?  There's a simple example posted on how the `.keys` and `.value` work. And take a look at the format of the data.

Comment: @Shashank if I do `.value(function(d){return +d["HIV/AIDS"]})` it return an empty array layers [ ], I I do `.keys([function(d){return +d["HIV/AIDS"]}])` it returns [0, NaN, data: {…}